# Hibernate restrictions.in function

Tags: java, hibernate

i'm trying to use Hibernate's `Restrictions.in("property", collection)` function where the collection contains complex Objects. It's not working so i was wondering if there is a limitation with this function, maybe it is limited only to Strings or numerical numbers because all examples i see are in that way.

I would like to compare something like this:

```
public class Edicion implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer edicionId;
    private Usuario editor;
    private Proyecto proyecto;
    private Date fecha;

    ...}
```

There is an objet of this class in the "property" and a collection of them in the Collection. Is it possible to find it this way??

Comment: have you implement hashCode and Equals for it?

Comment: ok, equals is not implemented, nice one! ;) but.. what do you mean with hashCode?

Comment: See: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode?_sscc=t    ----- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `Restrictions.in()` is used to generate part of a where clause of a SQL statement. Your database doesn't know anything about your Edicion class.

Comment: Now i think i got it, i guess the answer given by @JB Nizet explains it in a nice way. It's kind of extremely difficult to formulate a where clause with the whole object. 

But, in the other hand, it's true that my database doesn't know anything about my Edicion class, but Hibernate does, doesn't it?

Comment: If your class isn't an entity, no, it doesn't know about it. What's the type of your "property"? Could you please provide the code of your entity?